# How to make a call from javascript to jsp and from jsp to another url and get the values?

Tags: javascript, java, xml, jsp

I need to create a JSP in which it will send a request to an external system and get some values. These values need to be populated in my frontend javascript application. The logic is like the javascript will call the JSP and the JSP will get the values from an external system (some other server) and these values will be taken back to text boxes in javascript page.

Comment: javascript -> jsp ... lookup AJAX

Comment: I don't understand this--how does Javascript call JSP?  When Javascript runs, it's already in your browser, and by that time there shouldn't be any JSP as the server will have already translated it to HTML before sending it to the browser, since browsers don't understand JSP.  I'm guessing that you're using some terms very loosely, or incorrectly.  Maybe it would help to provide some code (at least a skeleton) to show us what you're trying to do?

Comment: Consider I have a servlet inside which data is there in XML format and there are textboxes in my frontend application which is in javascript.I need to get the values from the servlet to the Java layer using a JSP ,for example:var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); var flag = true;
 var jspLocation = 'abc.jsp';
 xmlhttp.open('POST',jspLocation, false);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml'); 
 xmlhttp.send(soap_req);      
 //xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
  { if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) 
   {   
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
     { 
 } something like this.